# Overmixed pate sucree

Tags: baking

I overmixed my pate sucree and it is now very soft (see picture). Is there any way I could fix it?

[image]

Recipe:
1/2 cup/120g cold butter
1/2cuo + 1 tbsp/ 70g icing sugar
1/4cup/25g ground almonds
1 pinch of coarse sea salt
A few drops of vanilla extract
1 egg
1 2/3 cup / 200 g cake flour.

I realised afterwards that i had added 120g instead of 200g of flour. It looks more dough like now. However, when i tried to roll it out, the pie dough feels very soft after i roll it out and was pretty impossible to remove from the floured surface. I think it might really be overworked..

Comment: Maybe chill it in the fridge and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Solution 1:
Use it as poundcake batter.
Judging by the photo, it looks a lot like perfect cake batter.

Solution 2:
Chill it well, work in the missing 80g flour, chill again.
Use as planned, accept that the pie crust might be a bit tougher than expected. Adding a pinch or two of baking powder to the flour can counteract it a bit.